# How to check system version and do the script under the stipulation

Tags: ios, bash, command-line, terminal

`Hey guys`. Please help!

I need to check iOS version and if `it's >=8.0` *(it can be 8.0 or 8.1 or 8.1.1 or 8.2)* do the first script, and `if it's <8.0` *(it can be 7.1.2 or 7.1 or 6.1.3 etc)* do the other one.

The checking command is `sw_vers -productVersion`
So I don't know how to make the script read the result of this command and then do the script under the stipulation.
Please help me how I can do it correctly!

I tried something like this

```
sw_vers -productVersion 
read -p num;
if [[ $num -lt 8 ]]; then
        echo "7";

else
        echo "8" 
fi
```

But in this case I need to push the enter button and I'm not sure that it works as it supposed to.

Comment: Please, post the output of the command `sw_vers -productVersion`

Comment: In my case the output is 7.1.2 (because iOS7.1.2. is installed; for other users it might be different)

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do what you need. Some ones: (1) pipe the output of the `sw_vers` command to a `grep` command (2) assign the output of the `sw_vers` command to a variable and check if that value starts with the characters `8.`

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply but I'm kinda noob in bash. Could you please write a complete solution? I mean a command which I should paste to my script to get I want :)

Comment: Try `IF=. read num _ <<<$(sw_vers -productVersion)`. Then the `num` variable should hold anything before the first dot from the output of `sw_vers` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IFS=. read num _ < <(sw_vers -productVersion)

if   [ "$num" -lt 8 ]
then
     echo "7 or lower"
else
     echo "8 or upper" 
fi
```

Comment: Error: line 3: [: 7.1.2: integer expression expected

Comment: the problem is not in IFS it's in: if ["$num" -lt 8]. There's an error in line3: [: 7 1 2: integer expression expected. And when I wrote IF it was 7.1.2., and when I wrote IFS it was 7 1 2 (with spaces)